macOS, how replace space in terminal file path output with something I can cmd + click?
I have an app where I download files into a system path. At the beginning of my program I'm outputting these paths to the terminal like so:

However as you can see there is a space in the middle, which means I cannot cmd + click to open the file directly (which is supported in vscode and iTerm). Is there any sort of replacement I can do to create a clickable path?
I already tried:
app_data_dir.unwrap().to_str().unwrap().replace(" ", "\\ ")

But although it outputs correctly it still cuts the link to only the first or second half.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I know, I wanted to show the actual highlighting

How is that relevant?

I believe it is relevant to show what the terminal actually renders

Found the response from one of the VSCode maintainers, seems there is no way to achieve this. Shame.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66825#issuecomment-456437451

This is by design, don't put spaces in your filenames if you want them to work in tools like this 

